# Horizontal video tearing

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, video, tearing

I am using Xubuntu 14.10 on Dell Vostro 5470 (GPU is Intel HD 4400).
I have serious problems with watching videos (no matter if on Youtube or on local storage), video keeps tearing when there are fast movements etc.
I installed Intel graphics installer, changed output in VLC to XCB, but nothing changed. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise,It is just small marginal tearing during high motion video correct? If so, I recently had this problem on Ubuntu and fixed it via compiz settings (setting `v sync` to `blank` and `undirecting full screen windows`). It is to my understanding that Xubuntu uses its own compositing/window manager so I wouldn't be awfully much help, but if you try playing around with that it may work. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60GJ0dJ1xmE) as a great reference tool for how much tearing was going on: btw I have the same intel HD 4400 GPU, I think this is the root of the problem haha. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I finally got Compton running, took me few days to find the right config file, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try these tips I found, if you have NVIDIA http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-fix-video-tearing-in-videos-nvidia-ubuntu